# Storing multiple variables. In java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking for a way in java (not sql), to store a few inputs. And be able to refer each entry.

So for example the Id of person entering info, date entered, a score of some kind (int).

All I can find is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Voting to close as it is too broad. I suggest read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dedicate some time to:[Java Data Structures Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274711/java-data-structures-reference)

Comment: Why don't you create your own class with fields you want to store? You can halter create array or list of instances of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution is to create a class for the data you want, for example:

```
public class Data {
    private int score;
    private String info, date;

    public Data(String info, String date, int score) {
        this.score = score;
        this.info = info;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Now you can create these objects with the data that the user inputs, and add them to a collection (i.e an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) or simply to an array. Here's an example with an array:

```
Data[] myData = new Data[4]; // 4 is an arbitrary maximum number of entries 

// Get the data into variables

// Now create a new Data object with the information and add it to the array
myData[0] = new Data(info, date, score);

// Repeat this process for all the input
```

Comment: Really good thank you.

Comment: TO ANYONE WHO COMES ACROSS THIS. What i was looking for at the time and now have come across is an ARRAY OF OBJECTS. you can create say a person and then have an array of person objects each with their own name etc. accessed via arrayname[1].getname(). This is what all these so called experts have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be done in many ways, the most accessible and understandable one probably being a List or ArrayList.

You seem to want to keep a list of Players, each having a few attributes. You could start by creating a Player object, like so

```
Class Player {
  Public Player(int score, String name) {
  this.score = score;
  this.name = name;

}

  private int score;
  private String name; 

 public void setScore(int score){
   this.score = score; 
 }

public int getScore(){
  return this.score; 
} 
// Repeat for all class variables
```

Then, you would declare an ArrayList in one of your other classes. Note that it has the parameter type Player.

```
ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

You can then add Player objects to the playerList like so:

```
Player p = new Player(345, "randomName"); 
playerList.add(p);
```

If you then want to access one of your Players, and one of their scores specifically, you would do this:

```
int currentPlayerScore = playerList.get(0).getScore();
```

Naturally, 0 here stands for the number of the ArrayList entry.

Good luck.